# google analytics embed API without google login to google analytics account

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I am trying to implement 'Google Analytics' where the resulted data should be imported into my site as a separate page.

When I use embed API, it asks for google analytics login before displaying the analytics data in the form of charts.. etc.

How to bypass the external google login for google analytics embed api.

We're using Angular JS to consume embed api.

Comment: I don't think you can. Google is not going to allow just anyone to get analytics data for a site. That data is protected to protect site owners and therefore would require a login.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The embed API requires that you have access to the data in order to view it.

If you want to have a dashboard publicly available of your data the best course of action is to:

- Query your data server side and store it in a database
- Query the database and query your database on page load and draw the charts.

This way you protect your google credentials doing the query server-side and also cache the data for faster retrieval when serving your pages and also to avoid hitting api limits.

Another option is to take a look at [SuperProxy](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-super-proxy). Which is an AppEngine Application you can deploy and does exactly the same job I described above.